# jQuery remove twice from get().join(', ')

Tags: jquery, checkbox

I have 2 checkboxes positioned in 2 different places on same page.

And, I am using the following code to append the checked values.

```
var checkboxes = $("#sercuisineslist input[type='checkbox'],#sercuisineslist2 input[type='checkbox']");
function docheck(){
    $('#myquery').val(
        checkboxes.filter(':checked').map(function(item) {
            return this.value;
        }).get().join(', ')
     );
}
checkboxes.on('change', function() {
    docheck();
});
```

When I check the same checkbox in 2 different areas then the same value is getting appended twice but this is never an issue in my scenario. But when I uncheck the checkboxes, I need to uncheck in both the areas so to ensure that appened value will be remove twice.

For example if African is checked the the textbox `myquery` shows as

African, African

And when I uncheck how can I ensure African is removed twice rather than once?

I tried something like

```
checkboxes.on('uncheck', function() {
    docheck();
    docheck();
});
```

and this didn't help me.

Comment: so here you can have `african` checkbox two times in different area of the page, when you click on both of them then `african` value getting added twice, And now you uncheck any one of the checkbox then two `african` values get removed instead of one,is that right?

Comment: @BhushanKawadkar - That's correct, it should be removed twice.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can uncheck the same checkbox by using name of it and then call docheck() function which will take only checked checkboxes, see below code

```
checkboxes.on('uncheck', function() {
    if(!this.checked)
   {
     var valueOfCheckbox = $(this).attr('value');
     $('input[type="checkbox"][value="'+valueOfCheckbox+'"]').prop('checked',false);
   }
    //call function to get checked values
    docheck();
});
```

**[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/x96oaqad/5/)**

Comment: Didn't work. http://jsfiddle.net/x96oaqad/ if I check twice it should append twice but if I uncheck once it should be removed twice.

Comment: The triggering information for uncheck is the value. The names of the checkboxes are probably different, why otherwise have two sets?